# Solving $y^2dx\:+\:\left(x^2+xy\:+\:y^2\right)\:dy\:=\:0$

Tags: calculus

$y^2dx\:+\:\left(x^2+xy\:+\:y^2\right)\:dy\:=\:0$

Can't see how to turn into a linear, or turn it into an exact.
Any hint?

Comment: Try dividing by $x^2$ it looks like it becomes nicer that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [first-order homogeneous ODE](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/first/homogeneous/homogeneous.html) since it can be written in the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ as shown below:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y^2}{x^2+xy+y^2}=-\frac{(\frac{y}{x})^2}{1+\frac{y}{x}+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}$$

In general, these types can be solved by the substitution $y=vx$, which by the product rule implies that $\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$. This will reduce your differential equation to a [separable](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx) one:
$$v+x\cdot \frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{v^2}{1+v+v^2}$$
$$x\cdot \frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{v^3+2v^2+v}{1+v+v^2}$$
$$\int\frac{v^2+v+1}{v^3+2v^2+v}~dv=-\int \frac{1}{x}~dx$$
The right hand side is easy to integrate. For the left hand side, use partial fractions, then the rest is easy:
$$\frac{v^2+v+1}{v^3+2v^2+v}=\frac{v^2+v+1}{v(v+1)^2}=\frac{A}{v}+\frac{B}{(v+1)^2}$$